# javascript how to make all strings italic after hyphen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

Good morning to all

I have a question related to my big commerce products title. here I need the first part of the product's title in bold and after the hyphen or dash the second part need in italic. But problem is that the  products title comes with one global variable %%GLOBAL_ProductName%% which I cannot make separated with the span tag. so can you suggest me how I can achieve the rest of strings after hyphen show in Italics with the help of javascript?

For example, check this screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/fKy0FhByzzl
and here is big commerce website http://rp-staging2.mybigcommerce.com/categories

```
<li class="%%GLOBAL_AlternateClass%%">
    <div class="ProductImage" data-product="%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductThumb%%
    </div>
    <div class="OutOfStockMessage InfoMessage" style="%%GLOBAL_ItemSoldOut%%">
        %%SNIPPET_SideAddItemSoldOut%%
    </div>
    <div class="ProductActionAdd" onclick="location.href='%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%';">
        <p><a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%" class="%%GLOBAL_SearchTrackClass%% pname">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>
        </p>
        <p><em class="p-price">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%% USD</em>
        </p>
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductURL%%" class="btn icon-%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductAddText%%</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%

this variable showing products name please check screenshot and website i have provided link

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question, along with some examples of product names as you receive them and how you'd like to see them formatted.

Comment: Thanks for reply did you check website link http://rp-staging2.mybigcommerce.com/categories

Comment: Hope you understand this need to done with big commerce which is showing all titles of products with one variable %%GLOBAL_ProductName%%

Comment: @nnnnnn check screenshot please http://prntscr.com/eeit9t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some of the cool es6 features (array destructuring and template literals)

```
$(".pname").each(function () {
    [beforeDash, afterDash] = $(this).text().split(" - ");
    $(this).html(`${beforeDash} - <i>${afterDash}</i>`);
});
```

Looks like:
[image]

Comment: perfect men, this one i exactly need .

Comment: We do not need to include space in split. Because split is needed only on (-). Split is needed only on first occurrence. str.split("-") returns array of words.

Answer (score 2):

And if you are using jQuery in your website, you can use something like this:

```js
$( window ).on( "load", function(){
  var text = $('.text');
  var x = text.text().split('-');
  text.html(`${x[0]} - <i>${x[1]}<i>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  Hello - World
</div>
```

Comment: This split won't work if the second part of the product name again contains  a dash(-). And also won't work for multiple div elements with same class name with different product names. It always takes latest product name.

Comment: The split will work, but it will not append it into the dom. For that purpose, we can iterate through the array and use append() to append the values into the dom. 
And in case of multiple elements we can use iterator to iterate through each element and use the logic using $(this). And my answer was not the solution to the problem but the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When ever possible do this kind of split at the server side. Because client side you will manipulate strings after loading the page. So it is not good to do at client side. But anyhow I have written jquery code to fulfill your requirement. I have written in a click event for demo purpose. Please do the logic on onload event.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
$(".productName").each(function(){
var title = $(this).text();
var firstSentence = "<b>"+title.substr(0,title.indexOf('-'))+"</b>";
var secondSentence = "<i>"+title.substr(title.indexOf('-')+1)+"</i>";

var finalTitle = firstSentence+ "-" + secondSentence;

$(this).html(finalTitle);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<a class="productName"> Sample1 - Product Name1</a><br>
<a class="productName"> Sample2 - Product Name2</a><br>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Change Format">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it helps...

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8p11mc/1/

You need to split your product name with '-' and then add these isolated names in separate spans and then you can style these spans as you want. I have written code for simple test case , you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
<html>
<script>
         var productName = 'ABC-XYZ';
         var separatedNames = productName.split('-');
         var firtsName = separatedNames[0];
         var secondname = separatedNames[1];

  window.onload = function() {
    //when the document is finished loading, replace everything
    //between the <a ...> </a> tags with the value of splitText
    document.getElementById("myTag").innerHTML = '<span>'+firtsName+'</span>-<span class="secondnameCls">'+secondname+'</span>';
  }

</script>

<body>
  <li class="%%GLOBAL_AlternateClass%%">
    <p><a id='myTag'></a></p>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```